# Не работает форматирование текста python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
text = '**жирный текст**'
bot.send_message(chat_id=user_obj.chat_id, text=text, parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Результат:

[image: Результат кода]

Пробовал использовать MarkdownV2, не помогло. Использовать HTML не могу, так, как нужно использовать `форматирование такого типа`, оно кстати, работает. Если есть аналоги этого форматирования в HTML, сообщите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это моноширинный текст, для `HTML` разметки используется тег `<code>`, а для `MarkdownV2` нужно использовать `*text*` согласно [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!